# GridData column value not updating when i update values (Java)

Tags: java, rcp

In Java RCP,
I am using following code snippet.

```
<Table>
<Column id="fname"/>
</Table>
</GridLayout>
```

Setting the values in java using following attributes

```
support.firePropertyChange("fname","oldValue", "newValue");
```

The thing is if i am trying to refresh the value, it is not getting refreshed with new values if i  click or move the cell, the value is not getting displayed with updated value. kindly help.

Comment: @greg-449 This is java Rich Client Platform

Comment: Which is nothing to do with Eclipse RCP (even if you happen to be using Eclipse to develop it)